# line break in tabularx environment

Tags: tables, line-breaking, tabularx, multirow, seqsplit

I have a complicated table with multicolumns that overflow. I believe I can't use `\seqsplit` because it's a tabular environment (inside a `tabularx`). I tried `\newline` and `\hline` but it didn't work either.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx, seqsplit}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h!]
    \centering
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{llX}
\hline
     \textbf{PCR} & \textbf{Template} & \textbf{Primers} \\
     \hline
     \textit{\#1} & 355. Pdat-1+intron &        \begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}}
                   \seqsplit{GCCTATTCCAGTATGACCCCTTTGAA}\\
                   \addlinespace
                   AGATACGGGTTTCACTTTTTCTACCGGTACCCTCCAAGG\\
                 \end{tabular}\\
    \hline
     \textit{\#2} & 399.Pdat-1::SEC-24.2::mKate::UTR & \begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}}
                   TACCGGTAGAAAAAGTGAAACCCGTATCTCAAATCCCAAATGG\\
                   \addlinespace
                   TTTGGATCAACATGAGCATTCGGATTCGC\\
                 \end{tabular} 
                 \\
         \hline
         \textit{Fusion} & Products from PCR\#1 and \#2 & \begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}}
                   GCCTATTCCAGTATGACCCCTTTGAA\\
                   \addlinespace
                   TTTGGATCAACATGAGCATTCGGATTCGC\\
                 \end{tabular} 
                 \\
         \hline
\end{tabularx}
\caption{Primers}
\label{tab:Primers_CSKD}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image: this is how my attempt looks like]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible solution is `\makecell` from `\makecell package`.

OFFTOPIC: In my opinion you should try to reduce the space of PCR and Template column to fit the whole primer sequence (most of it) on one line or at least give the orientation (5´-3´ end).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx,seqsplit}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2}

\begin{table}[h!]
    \centering
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} llX @{}}
\hline
     \textbf{PCR} & \textbf{Template} & \textbf{Primers} \\
     \hline
     \textit{\#1} & 355. Pdat-1+intron &        \begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}}
                   \makecell[l]{GCCTATTCCAGTATGACC\\CCTTTGAA}\\
                   \addlinespace
                   \makecell[l]{AGATACGGGTTTCACTTT\\TTCTACCGGTACCCTCCA\\AGG}\\
                 \end{tabular}\\
    \hline
     \textit{\#2} & 399.Pdat-1::SEC-24.2::mKate::UTR & \begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}}
                   \makecell[l]{TACCGGTAGAAAAAGTGA\\AACCCGTATCTCAAATCC\\CAAATGG}\\
                   \addlinespace
                   \makecell[l]{TTTGGATCAACATGAGCA\\TTCGGATTCGC}\\
                 \end{tabular} 
                 \\
         \hline
         \textit{Fusion} & Products from PCR\#1 and \#2 & \begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}}
                   \makecell[l]{GCCTATTCCAGTATGACCC\\CTTTGAA} \\
                   \addlinespace
                   \makecell[l]{TTTGGATCAACATGAGCAT\\TCGGATTCGC} \\
                 \end{tabular} 
                 \\
         \hline
\end{tabularx}
\caption{Primers}
\label{tab:Primers_CSKD}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]